# check for a column if it is null , over a previous term with some conditions

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, transactions, airflow

I have lets say two terms term A (previous)and term B (current) , i need to check if pol_cancl_date is null or not in term A , there is a transaction_sequence_number , i need to see if the pol_cncl_date is existing in the greatest A.transaction_sequence_number and if greatest( A.transaction_sequence_number ) is the greated when compared to all B.transaction_sequence_number numbers , if it is  then i would want to check for pol_cancl_dates's existence and apply a logic

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
      pol_num
      ,term_start_dt
      ,term_end_dt,pol_cancel_dt
      ,trans_seq_num
      ,future_cancel_dt
      ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY pol_num ORDER BY term_end_dt DESC) AS flag 
    FROM `gcp-ent-datalake-preprod.trns_prop_pol_hs_horison.prop_cost`
     --WHERE pol_num IN ('30766675','33896642')
    -- pol_num = '33288489' 
    ORDER BY term_start_dt, term_end_dt DESC
  ) 
)
SELECT
  *
  ,CASE
    WHEN prior_pol_cancel_dt IS NOT NULL AND current_trans_seq_num < prior_trans_seq_num THEN prior_pol_cancel_dt
    ELSE current_pol_cancel_dt
  END apply_cancelled_renewal_dt
FROM (
  SELECT
    MAX(a.pol_num) AS current_pol_num
    ,MAX(a.term_start_dt) AS current_term_start_dt
    ,a.term_end_dt AS current_term_ent_dt
    ,MAX(a.pol_cancel_dt) AS current_pol_cancel_dt
    ,MAX(a.trans_seq_num) AS current_trans_seq_num
    ,MAX(a.future_cancel_dt) AS current_future_cancel_dt
    ,MAX(a.flag) AS current_flag
    ,MAX(b.pol_num) AS prior_pol_num
    ,MAX(b.term_start_dt) AS prior_term_start_dt
    ,b.term_end_dt AS prior_term_end_dt
    ,MAX(b.pol_cancel_dt) AS prior_pol_cancel_dt
    ,MAX(b.trans_seq_num) AS prior_trans_seq_num
    ,MAX(b.future_cancel_dt) AS prior_future_cancel_dt
    ,MAX(b.flag) AS prior_flag
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM x WHERE flag=1) a
  INNER JOIN(
    SELECT * FROM x WHERE flag = 2 ) b 
  ON a.pol_num = b.pol_num AND a.flag = b.flag - 1 
  WHERE a.pol_cancel_dt IS NOT NULL
  AND b.pol_cancel_dt IS NOT NULL
  AND greatest(a.trans_seq_num) < b.trans_seq_num 
  -- AND a.trans_seq_num = GREATEST(a.trans_seq_num) 
  -- AND b.trans_seq_num = GREATEST(b.trans_seq_num)
  GROUP BY a.term_end_dt, b.term_end_dt
)
  --WHERE a.term_start_dt < b.term_start_dt
  --if prior term GREATEST (trans_sewq num
```

this logic is still not giving me some results , one thing is that trans_seq_num doesn't necessarily have to be one less

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. It is hard to provide a helpful answer from just the explanation and the (long) query.